Error term in SGD with momentum
I am reading the article "How Momentum really works" (https://distill.pub/2017/momentum/), and i am confused in one point:
I am trying to derive the convergence rate for momentum from the function:

$\min_{\alpha, \beta}\max\lbrace \parallel \begin{pmatrix}
   \beta & \lambda_1 \\
   -\alpha\beta & 1-\alpha\lambda_1
  \end{pmatrix}   \parallel, ..., \parallel \begin{pmatrix}
  \beta & \lambda_n \\
  -\alpha\beta & 1-\alpha\lambda_n
  \end{pmatrix}   \parallel  \rbrace$

$\parallel\parallel$ here denotes the magnitude of the maximum eigenvalue, and occurs when the roots of the characteristic polynomial are repeated for the matrices corresponding to the extremal eigenvalues. So we know that we have the eigenvalues for R:
$\sigma_i =\frac{1}{2}(-1+\alpha\lambda-\beta\pm\sqrt{(-\alpha\lambda+\beta+1)^2-4\beta})$
But somehow i do not figure out how to make the algebra here. First, I would like to know if it is right to equal the eigenvalues (one in terms of $\lambda_1$ and the other in terms of $\lambda_n$) and then you need to find solutions for alpha and beta? And then I do not really know which trick to apply to make the algebra to write it in terms of alpha.
So I guess i need to solve:
$\frac{1}{2}(-1+\alpha\lambda_1-\beta+\sqrt{(-\alpha\lambda_1+\beta+1)^2-4\beta})=\frac{1}{2}(-1+\alpha\lambda_n-\beta+\sqrt{(-\alpha\lambda_n+\beta+1)^2-4\beta})$
and
$\frac{1}{2}(-1+\alpha\lambda_1-\beta-\sqrt{(-\alpha\lambda_1+\beta+1)^2-4\beta})=\frac{1}{2}(-1+\alpha\lambda_n-\beta-\sqrt{(-\alpha\lambda_n+\beta+1)^2-4\beta})$
Is that correct?
